# MySQL Trigger: Delete From Table AFTER DELETE

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1046

Scope: Two tables.  When a new patron is created, they have some information about them stored into a 2nd table (This was done using a trigger as well, it works as expected). Here's an example of my table structure and relationship.

Table 1-> **patrons**

```
+-----+---------+-----+
+  id +   name  + val +
+=====+=========+=====+
+  37 +  george +  x  +
+-----+---------+-----+
+  38 +  sally  +  y  +
+-----+---------+-----+
```

Table 2 -> **patron_info**

```
+----+-----+----------+
+ id + pid +   name   +
+----+-----+----------+
+  1 +  37 +  george  +
+----+-----+----------+
+  2 +  38 +  sally   +
+----+-----+----------+
```

The administrator can manage the patrons. When they choose to remove a patron, the patron is removed from the **table 1** `patrons`. At this point, nothing happens to **table 2** `patron_info`.

I'm simply trying to create a trigger to delete from table 2, when table 1 has an item deleted. Here's what I've tried...

Initially, I try to drop the trigger if it exists (just to clear the air)...

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS log_patron_delete;
```

Then I try to create the trigger afterwards...

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_patron_delete AFTER DELETE on patrons
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM patron_info
    WHERE patron_info.pid = patrons.id
END
```

At this point, I get a syntax error `1046: Check syntax near END on line 6`. I don't know what the error is at this point. I've tried several different variations. Also, am I required to use a delimiter here?

Can anyone help restore my sanity?

Comment: What help would you need here? what is your real question?

Comment: @vivek_jonam The delete trigger won't fire. It gives me a sytnax error on 'END' at line 6. Also, do I wrap this in a `DELIMETER $$`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: just a note about memcache question - it was linked only after I added it. It was no in "Related" before I did it.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think there is an error in the trigger code.
As you want to delete all rows with the deleted patron ID, you have to use **old.id** (Otherwise it would delete other IDs)

Try this as the new trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_patron_delete AFTER DELETE on patrons
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM patron_info
    WHERE patron_info.pid = old.id;
END
```

**Dont forget the ";"** on the delete query.
Also if you are entering the TRIGGER code in the console window, make use of the delimiters also.

Comment: Maaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaan. It all ended up being the semicolon in my WHERE clause. I'm such a fool. Thanks for that vivek, it's appreciated!

Comment: Why use a compound statement block for just one statement? There's no requirement in the [`CREATE TRIGGER` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html) to do so.

Comment: dont forget the ";" - should be in BOLD

Answer (score 17):

Why not set ON CASCADE DELETE on Foreign Key `patron_info`.pid?

Comment: If the table engine supports foreign keys this solution should be prefered before using trigger to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
create trigger doct_trigger
after delete on doctor
for each row
delete from patient where patient.PrimaryDoctor_SSN=doctor.SSN ;
```