# sql delete with foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, one of them is a relation table, for example:

Table **People** has primary key : *peopleid*;
Table **Pet** has primary key : *petid*;
Table **Own** has two foreign keys: *peopleid* and *petid*, they together serve as the primary key of table **Own**

Now 
I'm trying to delete a person from Table People given *peopleid*, meanwhile, the pets this person own should be deleted, as well as the relationship stored in table **Own**

Please shed some light, thanks in advance!

**Edit:** My question is how to write the sql to achieve this.

Comment: Shed some light on what?  What's the question?

Comment: @LarryLustig I'm trying to write sql to achieve this..

Answer (score 5):

I think what you need is `ON DELETE CASCADE`.
Using this, you can automatically remove all the table references, if you delete a primary key row.

In your case, if you delete a person using `peopleid`, it will automatically remove the references from `Own` table.

**Sample SQL statement**

```
CREATE TABLE Own (
peopleid int(11) NOT NULL,
KEY peopleid (peopleid),
FOREIGN KEY (peopleid)
REFERENCES People (peopleid)
ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Since pet table has no foreign key to people table, you need to define a trigger to auto delete pet entries when people entries are deleted.

```
CREATE TRIGGER pet_delete AFTER DELETE on own
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Pet
    WHERE Pet.petid = old.petid;
END
```

After defining the cascade rule and trigger, if you execute:

```
DELETE FROM People WHERE peopleid = 3
```

it will automatically delete entries from `own` table with `peopleid = 3` and the corresponding `petid` from `Pet` table.

Check this link for more details.
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/
[MySQL Trigger: Delete From Table AFTER DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818191/mysql-trigger-delete-from-table-after-delete)

Comment: The ON DELETE CASCADE rule would work for removing associated rows from the `own` table when rows from the `people` table are deleted, but would not work for the `pet` table. (Because the foreign key is from the `own` table referencing the `pet` table.)

Comment: Yes you are right. For pet table, some trigger needs to be defined

Comment: as @spencer7593 mentioned in his answer, it's possible that a pet is owned by more than one person. In that case, I don't want to delete the pet in table Pet....How should I modify the trigger to achieve this?

Comment: oh, I can do this:  DELETE FROM Pet
    WHERE Pet.petid = old.petid AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Pet WHERE petid = old.petid);

Comment: I think it should be `... SELECT * FROM Own WHERE petid = old.petid`

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use a multitable DELETE statement, to delete rows from all three tables, for example:

```
DELETE o.*
     , t.*
     , p.*
  FROM pet t
  JOIN own o
    ON o.petid = t.petid
  JOIN people p
    ON p.peopleid = o.peopleid
 WHERE p.peopleid = :b_peopleid
```

But... there's an issue with foreign keys. The rows may be deleted in an order that causes foreign key constraints to be violated. This isn't a problem with MyISAM, since it doesn't enforce foreign keys. But with InnoDB, if there are foreign key constraints defined, this can be a problem Unfortunately, InnoDB doesn't (yet?) support deferrable constraints, so the closest workaround to this is to temporarily **disable** foreign key checks...

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0 ;
```

then the **DELETE** statement, and then **re-enable** the foreign key checks...

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

But this disables ALL foreign key checks in the session, not just the foreign keys defined on the tables referenced in the DELETE. So, this approach is less than ideal, because of the potential for introducing inconsistent data.

(For example, if there's another table with a foreign key that references pet.petid, and we delete the "parent" row from pet, that may leave a rows in the "child" table that reference a non-existent key.)

**DELETE row(s) from `pet`?**

The data model suggests that a `pet` may be related to more than one `people`. For example:

```
 
    pet:    petid    petname
            ------   -------
            1        Spot

    people: peopleid name
            -------- ------
            2        Jack
            3        Jill

    own:    petid    peopleid
            -------  --------
            1        2
            1        3
```

If we were to delete "Jack", we could remove the associated row in "own" (the relationship between "Jack" and "Spot". But in this scenario, "Spot" is also related to "Jill". There's another row in `own` that references "Spot", so we wouldn't be able to remove "Spot", without also removing "Spot"'s relationship to "Jill".

So, the question is, do we really want to delete "Spot" in this case?

If we do really want to delete "Spot", we would also need to remove that other row from `own` too, the one that relates "Spot" and "Jill". We can accomplish that using **two** references to the `own` table; one to get the relationship between "Jack" and his owned `pet`, and another to get *all* of the `own` rows that reference "Spot".

```
DELETE r.*
     , t.*
     , p.*
  FROM pet t
  JOIN own r
    ON r.petid = t.petid
  JOIN own o
    ON o.petid = t.petid
  JOIN people p
    ON p.peopleid = o.peopleid
 WHERE p.peopleid = :b_peopleid
```

On the other hand, if we don't want to remove "Spot", because the "Jill"/"Spot" row in `own` also references "Spot", we might be able to do something very similar.  (I don't a SQL example for this.)

---

Some other options for dealing with foreign key relationships that may be workable for your use-case are BEFORE DELETE triggers, and/or `ON DELETE` rules on the foreign key constraints.)

If we had ON DELETE CASCADE rules defined on the foreign keys from `own` that reference `people` and `pet`, we could allow that to remove the rows from `own`.

Then we could use that first example DELETE statement in my answer, and we could omit the reference to `o.*` in the DELETE list, and just specify `t.*` and `p.*`. (We still need the reference to the `own` table in the FROM clause, to get the relationship between `people` ("Jack") and `pet` ("Spot"), so we know which rows from `pet` to remove.

---

Otherwise, you could run three separate DELETE statements. But the order that the DELETE statements are executed may actually remove information you need, to determine which rows in the other tables need to be deleted. This means you would likely need to query the tables to find the rows to be deleted, save that information, and then perform the required deletes, in an appropriate order.

---

Another workable approach to this kind of "delete" problem is to emulate a delete with an update of a "deleted_flag" type column on the row.

That is, rather than issue a DELETE statement, the application instead issues an UPDATE to set a special purpose "deleted_flag" on each row. But, the application use cases have to be designed for this, and almost all the queries that look for "non-deleted" data need to incorporate predicates that exclude the "deleted" rows. If *logically* deleted rows do actually do need to be deleted from the tables, then the DELETE statements can be run by a separate batch process.