# Translate after delete trigger from MySql to Sql Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

How to write [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818191/mysql-trigger-delete-from-table-after-delete]) trigger for MS SQL Server?

**MySql version:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_patron_delete AFTER DELETE on patrons
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM patron_info
    WHERE patron_info.pid = old.id;
END
```

**Sql server version:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_patron_delete ON patrons AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM patron_info WHERE patron_info.pid = old.id;
END
```

Problem: `old.id` works for MySql, but not for MS SQL Server

Comment: How about delete cascade?

Comment: I Agree with juergen d - This is not a job for triggers, it's a job for a foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a job for triggers, it's a job for a foreign key constraint.
You should create a foreign key between the `patrons` table and the `patron_info` table, and create it with the option `delete cascade`.

```
ALTER TABLE patron_info 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_patron_info_patrons FOREIGN KEY (pid) 
    REFERENCES patrons(id) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This way, you can't have any rows in patron_info that is not related to the patrons table, and once you delete a row from the patrons table the corresponding rows in patron_info gets deleted automatically.