# Codeigniter - delete rows where column ending in X contains variable across multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model

First off, I have no idea if this is possible, was just brainstorming.

I have a system that tracks 'live jobs' for a company's clients. They all get a unique 'job_id' in the database (Auto Incrementing).

Now these jobs have about 20+ tables linked to them (or will) and I have been naming columns in a certain pattern, to keep them easy to read.

All materials have a column called 'material_job_id', data files have a column called 'data_job_id' and so on for the various tables

**What I was wondering is this:**

Is it possible to delete ALL rows where the column ending in 'job_id' has the value X(Variable)

If nobody knows a relatively clean workaround, I'll just have to go into each table individually.

I also want to note, my knowledge of SQL is a bit limited, so if you know a way in SQL, I'd appreciate it if you explained what it was doing along the way

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: in case you use a DB like mysql - its maybe a good example for using a Trigger - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818191/mysql-trigger-delete-from-table-after-delete

Comment: 20+ is rather a lot - and can be symptomatic of poor design. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @sintakonte I'll take a look at that, thanks!

Comment: @Strawberry these jobs are in depth. however there are only 16, I just guessed how many off the top of my head.

Comment: 16, 20. Either way, it reeks of poor design.

Comment: @Strawberry I honestly don't see how that is so, every job has materials/data/cells(which then have data/materials linked)/artwork/actions/data work/processed data/proofs/quality checks/seeds/tasks(then scheduled onto machines)/production work and they can and will have multiple rows of each of these. I honestly don't see an efficient and easy to use way to merge these into fewer tables. How I tend to work is, if there can be multiple of something for just 1 of its 'parent' put it in its own table.

Comment: I normally shy away of ERDs, but one might be useful in this instance.

Comment: The coding could maybe be simplified by using a db engine that supports  foreign keys and foreign key constraints. InnoDB is one such MYSQL engine. There are limits as to how deep a  `ON DELETE CASCADE` operation can be nested and 20 tables might be a problem. Depends on the key relationships I suppose. I tend to agree with other comments that the design might not be optimal.

Comment: I'll have a look at an ERD later, when I'm home and have a bit more time (never actually had to do one before) @DFriend thanks for your input. Unfortunately this is a big client, that fulfill's mailing jobs that can have a production count of over 1.5million so for example, they could end up with 50+ materials for 1 job, which could then be split between 10 cells on that job. I never saw anyway of merging tables together, because there are simple too many things that need to be on their own.

Comment: Also, at the moment not all the tables listed have '...job_id' they are just the ones that WOULD if what I was after was possible. I was hoping there was a way of only specifying part of a column name. Similar to how in a like statement you would use a % to specify anything can follow or prelude. ('job_title' LIKE '%123') or whatever it'd be