# SQL Server trigger: Delete From Table AFTER DELETE

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I have a parent table called `announcement` like this

```
create table announcement 
(
    aid int primary key, 
    name varchar,
    ......
)
```

and another table `cars` that inherits from `announcement` (tpt) like this

```
create table cars
(
     aid int primary key 
             foreign key references announcement(aid) on delete cascade,
     .....
)
```

I know that if I delete a row from `announcement`, that record will be deleted from `cars` too because of the "on delete cascade".

But I want to became sure that if any deletion from `cars` has been happened, that row would also be deleted from `announcement`.

I wrote a trigger than I learn from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818191/mysql-trigger-delete-from-table-after-delete)  like this:

```
create trigger delCarFromA 
on car
after delete 
as
begin 
    delete from announcement 
    where announc.aid = car.aid;
end;
```

but I get this error:

> The multi-part identifier "car.aID" could not be bound.

What should I do?

Comment: Cascades are one way, and go "up" the keys, not down; as in they delete rows where the row appears as a foreign key else where. Deleting a row int he **primary** table because a row where it was deleted as a foreign key would be an awful idea, as that would end up deleting far more than the 2 rows you were expecting (as `DELETE` on the primary key would then `CASCADE` again).

Comment: the delete trigger has a special table 'deleted 'that reflects the delete record. So instead of car.aid use deleted.aid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delCarFromA on cars
    FOR DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM dbo.announc
    WHERE aid IN(SELECT deleted.aid FROM deleted)
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

Your tables are 1:n related. An `announcement` can have many cars, a car can have one `announcement`. If you delete an `announcement` you delete all cars cascadingly. But the other direction would need a rule, e.g.

1. If one `car` gets deleted, its `announcement` with all its other cars must be deleted.

or

2. If an `announcement`'s last `car` gets deleted (i.e. the `announcement` has no cars) then the `announcement` must be deleted.

I assume you want the second rule. Ideally, your trigger would be an after-statement trigger, but SQL Server does not support this. Unlike defined in the SQL standard, every trigger in SQL Server is a `FOR EACH ROW` trigger implicitly.

In a `FOR EACH ROW` trigger you can access the deleted car row. But this is not done via `car.aid`, but with `(select aid from deleted)` in SQL Server.

If you want the second rule applied, as I assume, you also need an `EXISTS` clause to see whether the `announcement` still has cars.

```
create trigger delCarFromA on car
after delete
as
begin 
  delete from announcement a
  where aid = (select aid from deleted)
  and not exists
  (
    select null
    from car c
    where c.aid = a.aid
  );
end;
```

If you want to delete the `announcemmnt` even when it still has cars, then remove the `EXISTS` clause from the trigger.